# How to remove extra space between line of text and table

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In Word 2013, I want to be able to have the table flush with the line of text above it. That is to say, I don't want the extra line break. I indicated in red the area I want removed. How can I do this?

---

[image]

UPDATE: @Shevek there still is a bit of a space
[image: still space]

@Milena Petrovic I did so and you can see it in the screen shot.

Comment: That space is to allow for the tail of the `g`

Answer (score 5):

This is probably caused by Spacing on the text

Select the line of text, right click and select `Paragraph`

Set `Spacing` -> `After` to `0 pt`

Set `Spacing` -> `Line Spacing` to `Single`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To be sure why there is a gap, turn on the formatting symbols first

1. Click the Show/Hide in the menu
2. If there is a line, make sure it's deleted

[image]

3.On the **Home** tab, expand the **Paragraph** section (bottom right arrow)

4.
Set both Before and After values in the Spacing section to 0, and set the Line spacing to Single, as Shevek suggested