# Remove space between line and table in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-styles, line-spacing

I need to remove the mysterious space marked in this screenshot:

[image: Photo for Space between line and table]

I searched before and found some answers in this previous thread:
[How to remove extra space between line of text and table](https://superuser.com/questions/722791/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-line-of-text-and-table)
but unfortunately it didn't help in my case. All line spacing after the line is set to 0 and Single as well as all the line spacing in the table itself.

It's quite a mystery!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you already followed the suggestions given in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/722791/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-line-of-text-and-table) without success, I'm assuming you already set the paragraph spacing to the minimum, so we'll check the table settings.

Right click the table and select `Table Properties`.

[image]

**Is `Text Wrapping` set by any chance to `Around`?**

If so, try either of these two options:

**Option 1**

Click the `Positioning` button and set the vertical position to `0 cm` relative to `Paragraph`.

[image]

**Option 2**

Set `Text Wrapping` to `None`. This may slightly break the design of your document as it will move your table inline with the text and may require you to adjust it further.

Answer (score 1):

Check line spacing options in Word:

[image]

And try selecting line options after selecting text.

Check the results before and after:

**BEFORE:**
[image: Before]

**AFTER:**
[image: After]

Comment: The OP mentioned trying the advice in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/722791/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-line-of-text-and-table), which includes setting the spacing to the minimum, without success.

Comment: my comment entered in error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the extra space when creating a table in Word, highlight the table and go to "Table Properties." Go to the Row tab. Select "Specify Height" and type in 1.5. In Row Height is select "Exactly", and the extra space is no longer there. It took me a long time, but I figured it out. I wanted to help someone else because I know how annoying this process is. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing this is
Insert a row above.
Type the sentence.
Align the sentence to the bottom right left or center.
Now remove the borders.
Voila!